# Book: Science Fiction - Immortal captured on Earth and joins military

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, immortality

The book details a hero who is picked up on a destroyed Earth (not sure if sole survivor or not).  He is smarter, faster, stronger, etc than the other humans.

He becomes part of the military and does special operations.  He has a ship that is almost undetectable because you can't look directly at it.  He has children who inherit most of his abilities.

At the end of the book his mind is fractured and a local village brings him a girl once a year who he calls by the name of the love of his life.  He then sleeps with her.  They do this to continue to get children that will have his genetic abilities.  I don't know if he's long lived or immortal.

Comment: Can you add in any more details, like when you may have seen it, or read it. Or when it may have been published?

Comment: I wish I could - this has been a brain teaser for me for years.  I don't remember anything about date / name / author.  I know it's not much to go on but it was such a great book if I can ever find it again.

Comment: Try this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) it's been helpful in the past and is pretty good at helping people [edit] in details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like the [Forever Hero](http://www.lemodesittjr.com/the-books/forever-hero/forever-hero/) series by L.E. Modesitt Jr.

The only thing that I don't remember is an invisible ship, but his (and others in the books) have combat suits which are described as 'fade-blacks' (or something similar) which caused one's eyes to drift over them without being fully able to see them.

Comment: That's it!!  Thank you very much for the response.  This has been bugging me for years.